# Kafka cp-server fails message validation on a broker side

Tags: json, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I need to validate messages on a brokers side.

- I run `cp-server` (merely ran [cp-all-in-one](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.3.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) compose file).
- created a topic
- set `confluent.value.schema.validation` to true
- registered a schema (JSON)
- produced a message

It always fails. Why validation fails? Should I change configuration?

Schema:

```json
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/models/data-item-definition.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "description": "test data item 1",
  "properties": {
    "array_val": {
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "type": [
        "array",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "int_val": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "string_val": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "string_val",
    "int_val"
  ],
  "title": "data item",
  "type": "object"
}
```

Message:

```json
{
  "string_val": "text",
  "int_val": 10,
  "array_val": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

Comment: Typo? You are missing a quote on `"three"`

Comment: With the quote it validates just fine: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/CAn9YesC

Comment: That was a typo in example. Thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue is that if `confluent.value.schema.validation` is true then to produce a message we need to send a magic byte and a schema ID at the beginning.

See [Wire Format](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#compatibility-guarantees-across-cp-versions).